# Distribute file to many folders

Tags: windows-7, windows

I need a way to put a new file in many folders on the same drive. Does windows 7 have a native way of handling thisor is there a batch method or some other way? My system is Windows 7 SP1 64bit.

My existing folder structure is: C:\Companyname\Companyname jobs\job

Each job folder has the name format: clientname_someplace.067

Within each folder is a subfolder - quotes invoices.hours.tc

How do I a traverse all job folders to propagate or distribute a new file to each quotes invoices.hours.tc subfolder?

the filetypes I want to distribute could be anything but are generally excel files (.xlsm), .txt files and open office files (.odt files).

Comment: As you suggest, use a batch file. `For` will probably be your friend if you wish to make it dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Get a batch or Powershell script to iterate through the directory structure, check the name of the current folder, if it fits, copy the files. Here is a Powershell example, careful, it iterates through the whole drive, adapt it to your particular needs!:

```
$targetdir = "C:\company\CompanyJobs\0jobTest\" + "whatever\you\need\to\concatenate"
$dirs = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse $targetdir
foreach ($d in $dir){
    if ($d.Name -eq "quotes invoices.hours.tc")
            # could also be: -like "quotes invoices.*"
        {
            Copy-Item -Path c:\path\to\source\file.xlsx -Destination $d.FullName
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll go away and think about that, I suppose I can insert any path after Recurse? e.g. C:\Companyname\Companyname jobs\

Comment: Yes, if your path contains spaces enclose it in quotes.

Comment: I tried the above script and got an error:
Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'c'.
At line:1 char:34
+ $dirs = Get-ChildItem -Directory -c:\company\CompanyJobs\0jobTest\
+                                  ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Comment: @nigelc: try concatenating your folder string in a variable and pass that to get-childitem

Comment: Hmmm - Thanks but what does that mean? I've had a good hunt around about concatenation in powershell and haven't found anything that looks right - I know this site doesn't exist for 'recipe' requests but it'd take me a month of sundays to work that out

Comment: I changed the code above

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create symbolic links.  Here is an article that discusses one way to do it: [http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/).

```
link="C:\Companyname\Companyname jobs\job\file.xls"
target="C:\Companyname\Companyname jobs\job2\file.xls"
mklink /D $link $target
```

Comment: Thanks Axe - I hadn't heard of those, they will be very useful, but in this case once I distribted the files I will then modify them